# Fortnite Screen Won't Resize PC

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

This might be a bug, but I really can't be sure. I'm probably doing something wrong, so I'm here to ask you guys!

So I have been playing Fortnite Battle Royale recently, and this is new: My window won't resize. When I actually launch Fortnite it remains this tiny little box. I can't change it in any way. When I click the fullscreen icon, it just fullscreen either horizontally or vertically, but it doesn't cover the entire screen.

Am I doing something wrong or is Fortnite being really buggy? And has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer lately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little unwanted bug in Fortnite . In game, if you want to use these buttons, you will need to click the button a little longer *(half second clicks won't work, hold for like 2 seconds then release)*. I found myself once double-quick clicking the full screen button with no success. Also happens with the Quit button.

There is another fix which always launches the game in full-screen and avoids future hassles. In Menu, Settings (Top Right, Three horizontal bars), you should see a setting called **window** in ***Video***, Change *Windowed* Option to *Full-Screen* Option and click Apply in the Bottom Right.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:
Press Alt + Enter and it should fill up your screen with fortnite.
It will stretch the resolution though, so maybe fiddle with the resolution settings until you get it right.